# Why is Jest testing my scripts.js file instead of scripts.test.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs

### I am trying to write tests for my javascript game using Jest for the first time. When I run the tests, Jest is giving me this error:

FAIL  ./scripts.test.js
● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined

  87 |
  88 | //  close button for modal
> 89 | span.onclick = function() {
     | ^

  90 |     modal.style.display = "none";
  91 |   }
  92 |
```

---

I have a scripts.js file that has the code for the card game, and scripts.test.js for the tests. I created a test function in the scripts.js file and then wrote a test for it in scripts.test.js just for the sake of testing.
When I run the tests I'm getting this error pointing a function inside of scripts.js.
Function in scripts.js:
[image]

My scripts.test.js file:
[image]

I don't understand why Jest would show a failed test for something that isn't in my scripts.test.js. Also, it's not testing the `addTwo` function that is in my scripts.test.js file, which is the only function I exported out of scripts.js.

### Any help would be greatly appreciated. THANKS!

```
package.json:
{
  "name": "cardGame",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "scripts.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
```

---

Comment: This question doesn't have all the necessary information needed to answer it. Namely, the object `span` isn't clearly defined. How is that item being created?

Comment: @Cory Collir, I made some edits to possibly make it easier to understand the issue. I didn't do a great job explaining. (Thanks for your edits...first post).

Comment: It still doesn't explain how it's created. Any way, the problem is that it isn't. It's undefined as the error states. The error happens on `require` line. Since it's not caught, test file isn't executed any further, that's how JS works. The test itself doesn't run because it wasn't declared.

Comment: I can only guess that 'span' does not exist. Jest is working by telling you that.